# String conversion when using labels

Tags: apex, customlabel, label

I am going to use a label in Apex code and compare it with another String variable.
Example: Comparison

```
Label.MyLabel == MY_VARIABLE;
```

Do I need to first convert the label to String before comparing? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: No your label will return String only.

Comment: I haven't tried to compile yet. Was just thinking of a solution approach and had this question. Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need to convert Label into String. All Labels are in String and compare with other String variable.

Have you get any error while doing this?